# Xamarin Forms Listview - Using custom view cell for each item in items source

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I am not sure if this is possible or if there are any recommended ways to achieve this. Essentially, I'm trying to have a list view with "jagged" or differing view cells foreach cell in the list view. As a super simple example, I am trying to dynamically display a button, label, and entry each in their own row of the list view. Here is my code:

XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Chaser.Views.Admin_Detail_MasterDetail_View">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                     Spacing="15"
                     Margin="10">
            <Label Text="{Binding ViewTitle, Mode=OneWay}"
                   FontSize="Large"
                   TextColor="Red"
                   FontAttributes="Bold" />
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemViews, Mode=OneWay}"
                      SelectionMode="None"
                      PropertyChanged="ListView_PropertyChanged">
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Codebehind

```
public Admin_Detail_MasterDetail_View()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DetailViewContext = new Models.Detail_MasterDetail_Model();
        DetailViewContext.ViewTitle = "Info";

        DetailViewContext.ItemViews = new List<ViewCell>
        {
            new ViewCell
            {
                View = new Button
                {
                    Text = "TestButton"
                },
            },

            new ViewCell
            {
                View = new Label
                {
                    Text = "TestLabel"
                }
            },

            new ViewCell
            {
                View = new Entry
                {
                    Placeholder = "TestEntry"
                }
            }
        };

        BindingContext = DetailViewContext;
    }
```

Note: This was also tried with adding stack layouts to the views then adding the individual items to the stack layouts, either way I get the following:

[image]

If possible, I would like to have command bindings on a per cellview basis as one type of cell may have differing context menu actions than another.

In the end the view cells will be much more complicated than a simple button or label, but this is for conceptual purposes to see if something like this is possible/recommended.

After some brief research I see there is a data template selector we can create, however, I am not sure if it would apply in this scenario. At the very least, I am not sure if it would allow for custom context menu actions on a per cell basis.

Thank you for any input on this!

Comment: You bind a ListView to a data source and let it build the UI based on a template.  You don't bind it to a list of UI elements.  If every cell is different, or mostly different, then using a ListView may be the wrong approach, vs just building up the UI manually.

Comment: For some Items of the same UI,, you can check DataTemplateSelector: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector

Comment: If you use  custom view cell for each item, Listview should not be appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a data template selector to achieve this. I created custom view cells then  in the data template selector, I have a data template object for reach template which gets set to the corresponding view cell.

Following [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector) Microsoft doc, it was fairly simple to configure. This also allows me to have custom view cell context actions defined for each type of view cell.

Answer (score -2):

After a so much Research i created below code Listview with Test data.

just copy and paste the code and check the result.

```
        <ListView HasUnevenRows="true"
                  RowHeight="200">
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>Item One</x:String>
                    <x:String>Item Two</x:String>
                    <x:String>Item Three</x:String>
                    <x:String>Item Four</x:String>
                    <x:String>Item Five</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Frame BorderColor="Red" Padding="0">
                            <Grid Margin="10">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="90" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <BoxView Grid.Row="0"
                                         Grid.Column="0"
                                         Color="Yellow" />
                                <BoxView Grid.Row="0"
                                         Grid.Column="1"
                                         Color="Black" />
                                <BoxView Grid.Row="1"
                                         Grid.Column="0"
                                         Color="Green" />
                                <BoxView Grid.Row="1"
                                         Grid.Column="1"
                                         Color="Blue" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding}"
                                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                                       TextColor="Red"
                                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Frame>
                </ViewCell>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```